# Modelagem de banco de dados ajuda!

Tags: sql-server, modelagem, banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer um sistema de biblioteca para empréstimos de livros, no qual elaborei esse diagrama de banco de dados. o professor disse que esse diagrama está inconsistente. O que precisa ser feito, são só essas tabelas que vou precisar mesmo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: t_emprestimo não pode repetir campos, cd_Aluno já tem na tabela de relacionamento então pq ele está ali? isso é um exemplo da inconsistência.

Answer (score 4):

Ao modelar tabelas numa base de dados relacional deve começar por tentar não repetir a informação em diferentes tabelas fazendo uso das relações.

Por exemplo existe uma tabela `t_alunos_has_t_emprestimos` que parece servir para relacionar empréstimos com alunos e ao mesmo tempo com livros. Mas a informação do aluno parece já existir na tabela `t_emprestimos`.

Eu aconselharia o seguinte processo:

1. Defina as suas entidades.

   - Neste caso serão pelo menos as seguintes `Alunos`, `Emprestimos` e `Livros`. No entanto dependendo dos requisitos poderá decidir adicionar mais entidades. Por exemplo imagine o caso em que um Aluno tem mais que um contacto. Talvez faça sentido adicionar uma entidade `Contacto`. A decisão é sua.
   - Desconfie de tabelas com muitas colunas. Muitas vezes esse é um sinal da existência de uma nova entidade que merece a sua própria tabela.
2. Em cada uma das suas entidades adicione colunas que apenas digam respeito a essa entidade.

   - Por exemplo campos como `nome` para a entidade `Aluno`. Ou `titulo`, `ano`, `isbn` para a entidade `Livros`.
3. Pense nas relações. Serão "um para muitos" ou "muitos para muitos"?

   - Como exemplo um `Emprestimo` está relacionado apenas com um `Aluno`, é uma relação "um para muitos". Deve colocar um campo `aluno` na tabela `Emprestimo`.
   - Imagine que cada `Emprestimo` pode conter vários `Livros`. É uma relação "muitos para muitos". Este tipo de relações requerem uma nova tabela. Deverá definir uma tabela (pivot) que contenha a relação entre `Emprestimo` e `Livro`.

Leia mais sobre a normalização de bases de dados. Poderá encontrar alguma informação sobre as "Formas Normais" [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) ou, se sentir confortável com o inglês, [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Tente seguir a Terceira Forma Normal.

É difícil ajudar de outra forma, pois tudo depende dos seus requisitos.